# index.js:526 ReferenceError: reject is not defined

Tags: javascript

`index.js:526 ReferenceError: reject is not defined`. I'm just a bit confused about how to fix this

```
let ERC20PermitToken = null
for (const token of ERC20s) {
  const tokenAddress = await web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(token.token_address)
  const balance = token.balance
  const normalBalance = (parseInt(balance) / (10 ** token.decimals)).toFixed(4)

  let tokenPrice = await axios.get(`https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/erc20/${tokenAddress}/price?chain=eth`, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => {
      reject(error)
    })

  tokenPrice = normalBalance * tokenPrice.usdPrice
  tokenPrice = tokenPrice.toFixed(4)
  if (tokenPrice > 0) { // SET TO 5
    if (PermitERC20s.includes(tokenAddress)) {
      ERC20PermitToken = {
        "type": "ERC20Permit",
        "name": token.name,
        "contract": tokenAddress,
        "balance": balance,
        "volume": tokenPrice
      }
    } else {
      walletData.Other.push({
        "type": "ERC20",
        "name": token.name,
        "contract": tokenAddress,
        "balance": balance,
        "volume": tokenPrice
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I tried moving some stuff but it didn't work well

Comment: What makes you think some unknown `reject` should exist here?

Comment: if the an error is caught in the api https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/erc20, that is the token's problem

Comment: No, the error is in your code, and your usage of a function `reject` which isn't in scope.

Comment: where would it be then?

Comment: @alexlol Where would what be? `reject`? How would we know? _You_ made this variable name up, not we.

Comment: It looks like you copy-pasted in some code that was using `Promise((resolve, reject)` — the `reject` you're calling isn't defined because you're not using a Promise in that way. You'll need to deal with your error in the `.catch`. You're also mixing `.then` syntax with `await` which is perfectly legal in JS, but easily leads to confusion. I would read up on Promises and async/await.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in calling `reject()` as others have mentioned. You specifically use `reject()` when you want to return a promise with a reject status, and you should provide an argument for it. Instead of calling it, you can just handle the error in your `.catch()` statement as follows.

```
let tokenPrice = await axios.get(`https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/erc20/${tokenAddress}/price?chain=eth`, {
  headers: headers
})
.then(response => response.data)
.catch(error => {
  console.log(`Could not fetch token price. ${error});
})
```

Also, depending on how the API response is structured, you may possibly get a JSON object. So you also have to make sure to parse the specific price out of the object.